# how to add a css file in a jsp file

Tags: css, spring-mvc, jsp, netbeans

[this is the screenshot of the project.I have to add index.css which is in staticResources to index.jsp.How to do it.Also,do i have to make any changes to the Disptacher Servlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOzwF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to the top of your page

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

And then include your CSS in this way

```
<link href="<c:url value="path"/>" rel="stylesheet">
```